# MDX Count with a Filter?

Tags: filter, count, mdx

We want to count the weeks where "Inventory Units" were greater then 0.
I have put this together but it doesn't quite work, it counts all weeks for an item not just the ones where Inventory > 0. I have tried some filters but they always result in #error as the result

```
WITH 
  SET [PreviousSixWeeks] AS 
    Tail
    (
      Filter
      (
        [Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Week]
       ,
        [Measures].[Inventory Units] > 0
      )
     ,6
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[INVWeekCount] AS 
    DistinctCount(PreviousSixWeeks*[Measures].[Inventory Units]*[Item].[Item Code]) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[INVWeekCount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Item].[Item Code].[Item Code]} ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {[Location].[Location].&[64]} ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      {
        [Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[2].&[8]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[2].&[9]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[3].&[10]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[3].&[11]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[3].&[12]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[3].&[13]
      } ON COLUMNS
    FROM [RFP]
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to count weeks with inventory, make sure it returns desired results then add any filters you want.

```
  WITH MEMBER [Measures].[InvWeekCount] AS 
         FILTER([Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Week].MEMBERS, 
         [Measures].[Inventory Units]>0).COUNT
  SELECT [Measures].[InvWeekCount] ON COLUMNS,
           [Item].[Item Code].[Item Code].MEMBERS ON ROWS
  FROM [Test Cube]
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to avoid `Filter` if you can as its performance is not great:

```
WITH 
  SET [PreviousSixWeeks] AS 
    Tail
    (
      [Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Week].MEMBERS
     ,6
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[INVWeekCount] AS 
    Count(NonEmpty((EXISTING PreviousSixWeeks),[Measures].[Inventory Units])) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[INVWeekCount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,{[Item].[Item Code].[Item Code]} ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {[Location].[Location].&[64]} ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      {
        [Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[2].&[8]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[2].&[9]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[3].&[10]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[3].&[11]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[3].&[12]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[3].&[13]
      } ON COLUMNS
    FROM [RFP]
  )
);
```

But this is a better way of doing Count with a filter criterion - it performs a lot better:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[InvWeekCount] AS 
    Sum
    (
      Time.[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Week].MEMBERS
     ,IIF
      (
        (NOT 
          IsEmpty([Measures].[Inventory Units]))
       ,1
       ,0
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[InvWeekCount] ON COLUMNS
 ,[Item].[Item Code].[Item Code].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {[Location].[Location].&[64]} ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      {
        [Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[2].&[8]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[2].&[9]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[3].&[10]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[3].&[11]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[3].&[12]
       ,[Time].[Yr-Qtr-Per-Wk-Day].[Fiscal Year].&[2016].&[1].&[3].&[13]
      } ON COLUMNS
    FROM [RFP]
  )
);
```

---

**note**

in terms of simple `AdvWrks` code this is what you're using:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[InvWeekCount] AS 
    Filter
    (
      [Product].[Product].[Product]
     ,
      [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity] > 0
    ).Count 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[InvWeekCount] ON COLUMNS
 ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

But this is the recommended efficient method:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[InvWeekCount] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [Product].[Product].[Product]
     ,IIF
      (
        (NOT 
          IsEmpty([Measures].[Internet Order Quantity]))
       ,1
       ,NULL
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[InvWeekCount] ON COLUMNS
 ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```